# How to check how many arrays are inside a file?

Tags: javascript

I have a js file like this

```
// app.js

let arr1 = ['first array'];
let arr2 = ['second array'];
```

Now, I have 2 arrays in my app.js file. Is there any way to check how many arrays are inside this app.js file?

Comment: no, you have one array, referenced by three variables

Comment: @JaromandaX Now?

Comment: arrays you defined? or all the arrays in its `this` context?

Comment: there are two, because you made two ... it's easy to count

Comment: Is there any way to count it in programming?

Comment: what is your end goal? because there are a few ways to do that, but not in a way "count arrays in a file"

Comment: It doesn't make any scene to count the variable defined inside a file;

Comment: you could create a custom class which `extends Array`, and then increment a counter variable. You'd need to create the arrays using your new class's constructor

Comment: Judging from the upvotes, this question must be perfectly clear, and there is some attempt hiding somewhere, which i am too blind to see. Many here seem to assume the file is being run. I don't see any hint on the question to assume that though, why would code analysis run the code? Also, can any assumptions be done about the file? It looks like one array literal per variable declaration, but can the code become more complex? What does "check how many arrays are inside this js file" mean? I must be really tired or something...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to achieve that...

```
Object.keys(window).forEach( (key) => { 
  if (Array.isArray( window[key] )) { 
      console.log(`${key} is an array`);  
  } 
});
```

But that will only work for global objects (i.e, objects attached to the window global variable)

Edit: as suggested from the @Mhmdrz_A's comment, you can write a function that checks an object for the existence of arrays:

```
function getArrayCount(object) {
   let count = 0;
   Object.keys(object).forEach( (key) => { 
      if (Array.isArray( object[key] )) { 
          count += 1;  
      } 
    });
    return count;

}

let anyObject = { someArr: [], anotherArray: [], yetAnother: []};

console.log(getArrayCount(anyObject)); // 3
```

But again, that will only check the outer layer of properties for the object you pass in. You will have to recursively check each property to see if there are nested arrays, etc.

Comment: You can pass `this` instead of `window` to iterate over that context instead of global context;

Comment: @Mhmdrz_A Thanks. I have updated my answer according to your suggestion